# SIGFPE Error, Why?

Tags: delphi

I have the following code:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  cpic: tcomponent;
  whichcol: integer; // have tried extended types
  whichrow: integer; // have tried extended types
begin
  for cpic in form1 do
  begin
    if (cpic.ClassType = timage) and (cpic.Tag = 10) then
    begin
      whichcol := timage(cpic).left - left div gap;
      whichrow := timage(cpic).Top - top div gap;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

This results in the following error:

> Error
>
> Project project1.exe raised exception class 'External: SIGFPE'.

With: as the outlined error:

```
whichcol := (timage(cpic).left - left) div gap;
```

Should the equation not just return a number value?

Comment: Would you mind giving more details about your environment? SIGFPE is a *Unix* signal, but Delphi is a *Windows* development tool. Are you actually using Free Pascal and the FCL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SIGFPE = Floating Point Error.

Sounds like a division by zero.  You sure `gap` is non-zero?

Comment: Ah, that fixed the problem. Funny though, I did try that at one point. I must have put it in incorrectly, thank you.

Comment: @user: Welcome to StackOverflow.  I'm glad you were able to find an answer to your question so quickly.  If an answer fixes your problem, it's customary to mark the answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark icon under the voting widget to the left of the answer. This rewards the answerer with reputation points and lets the rest of us know that the question has already found a satisfactory answer.